# Parallel on C++ isn't fast like C#

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I have code like this on **C#**

```
private static Random random = new Random();
public static string RandomString(int length)
{
    const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
      .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}
     Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {       
                 System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0L, 10000000, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 10 }, n =>
                 {
                 Console.WirteLine(RandomString(12));
                 });
                }
```

Add parallel method to it, it manage to run generate 10 millions random string in less than 8 seconds & use all CPU power

[image]

I tried to do it again in **C++**

```
string NonRepeatChar(int max_len)
{
    std::string valid_chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
    std::shuffle(valid_chars.begin(), valid_chars.end(), g);
    std::string rand_str(valid_chars.begin(), valid_chars.begin() + max_len);
    return rand_str;
}
```

Applied the code to some recommend **C++** parallel method

```
void multiply()
{
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {           
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
        {
            printf("%s\n",NonRepeatChar(10));
        }           
    }
}
}

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() : counter_(0) {}

    std::pair<string, std::future<void>> a_function(std::future<void>& f) {
        // Ensure that the background task from the previous iteration
        // has completed
        f.wait();

        // Set the task for the next iteration
        std::future<void> fut = std::async(std::launch::async, &Foo::background_task, this);

        // Do some work
        string value = NonRepeatChar(12);

        // Return the result and the future for the next iteration
        return std::make_pair(value.c_str(), std::move(fut));
    }

    void background_task() {
        ++counter_;
    }

private:
    std::atomic<int> counter_;
};
```

Record the time when run it

```
int main()
{   
    clock_t tStart = clock();
    std::future<void> bleak = std::async(std::launch::deferred, []() {});

    Foo foo;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        // Call the function
        std::pair<string, std::future<void>> result = foo.a_function(bleak);    
        bleak = std::move(result.second);   
        std::cout << result.first << "\n";
    }
    printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
    }
```

Here're my result:

> 10.98s//normal loop
>
> 8.76s//multiply
>
> 8.88s//Foo

Obviously the code didn't have any difference compare to original loop, only generate 10000 line, & it didn't even use all CPU power like **C#**. Is there something wrong with the parallel method? How may I optimize it?

Comment: What C++ compiler flags did you use to compile your program?  If you're running an unoptimized or "debug" build, the information you're showing us concerning timing information is meaningless.

Comment: Visual Studio, same with C#. all the method i used doesn't involve external libraries if that's what you asking?

Comment: No, what I'm asking is if you're running a "Debug" version of the C++ code.  If so, then change your configuration to "Release" and rebuild your code.  In general, any question involving how fast or slow C++ code seems to be must be accompanied by the compiler options used to build the test code.

Comment: i just change mode to "Release" & the performance stay the same

Comment: Good.  The point is that we get too many questions having to be closed, deleted, or abandoned due to the original poster not running a release version, and then finding out that the release version is much faster, making the question meaningless.  Benchmarks must always be accompanied by the options used to build the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple single-threaded example of what can be done with a hybrid C/C++
approach. Game developers use methods which are hybrids of "formal" C++ code
and look less like python. Of course, like Marmite, you love it or hate it, but regardless, the results speak for themselves.

I apologise if this is more to learn that you thought.

This particular example generates 10M strings in 3.682s on a single thread on my old AMD box.
You can launch a small number of async workers (< std::thread::hardware_concurrency()) to carve the work up into chunks of around a million cycles. You would then have synchronisation issues with your I/O, so be careful and avoid mutexes!

To go much faster, you need to unroll loops manually, use SIMD arithmetic and so on. For example, this case would work well with SIMD permute vectors.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// This is typical of the random number generators used in professional games.
// It is less "correct" than mersenne twisters, for example, but much faster.
inline uint32_t fast_rand(int32_t &seed, uint32_t limit) {
  // Prevent infinite loops.
  //if (limit == 0) return 0;

  // Make a mask that has all 1s in the bottom few bits.
  // This reduces the number of iterations of the loop to ~1
  int leading_zeros = __builtin_clz(limit);
  int mask = 0xffffffff >> leading_zeros;

  // Loop until our result is in range using rotate and xor.
  do {
    seed = (seed << 1) ^ ((seed >> 31) & 0xa53a9be9);
  } while ((seed & mask) >= limit);

  return seed & mask;
}

int main() {
  // I'm using two seeds to prevent coupling.
  // On their own, their quantiles are pretty flat, but
  // in this example they couple, causing conditioning in the results.
  int32_t length_seed = (int32_t)0x95abcfad;
  int32_t swap_seed = (int32_t)0xba7235fab;

  for (int i = 0; i != 10000000; ++i) {
    // Note we don't use a std::string. These are very slow.
    char chars[] = 
      "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    auto num_chars = sizeof(chars) - 1;
    auto length = fast_rand(length_seed, num_chars-1) + 1;

    // Trim the string to the right length.
    chars[length] = 0;

    // Shuffle the characters.
    for (int j = 0; j != length; ++j) {
      int swapper = j + fast_rand(swap_seed, length - j);
      auto tmp = chars[j];
      chars[j] = chars[swapper];
      chars[swapper] = tmp;
    }

    // Print with puts (not iostreams).
    puts(chars);
  }
}
```

For "hot loop" examples like this you should check your result on godbolt or similar.

clang with -O3 -mlzcnt gives the following inner loop.

```
.LBB0_4:                                #   Parent Loop BB0_1 Depth=1
    mov     rsi, rax
    sub     rsi, rdx
    lzcnt   ecx, esi
    mov     edi, -1
    shr     edi, cl
.LBB0_5:                                #   Parent Loop BB0_1 Depth=1
    lea     ecx, [rbx + rbx]
    sar     ebx, 31
    and     ebx, -1522885655
    xor     ebx, ecx
    mov     ecx, ebx
    and     ecx, edi
    cmp     rsi, rcx
    jbe     .LBB0_5
    add     ecx, edx
    mov     sil, byte ptr [rsp + rdx]
    movsxd  rdi, ecx
    mov     cl, byte ptr [rsp + rdi]
    mov     byte ptr [rsp + rdx], cl
    mov     byte ptr [rsp + rdi], sil
    add     rdx, 1
    cmp     rdx, rax
    jne     .LBB0_4
```

Comment: i have an error "'__builtin_clz': identifier not found". How may i fix this?

Comment: I guess this depends on your compiler. If you are not using gcc/clang, you could use one of the bit twiddling hacks such as: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2

Comment: int mask = limit - 1;
    mask |= mask >> 1;
    mask |= mask >> 2;
    mask |= mask >> 4;
    mask |= mask >> 8;
    mask |= mask >> 16;

Comment: i just replace 'mask' value like you suggest & run the code. It still took 6-7s to generate 10000 random string, it take even longer if you set specific string length for it. I use 'parallel_for' on it & the performance didn't get any better

Comment: There may be many reasons for this as suggested above. The take away is to check the assembly output and see if it is as short as the code above. Much will depend on your compiler and settings. Experiment and learn to get the desired result.

Comment: Are there any more code available to print millions of randoms tring per second on C or C++? i found everywhere on the site & seems to find none

Answer (score 2):

Your C++ code is not at all equivalent to your C# one.

**On the C# side**,

You are using a [`Parallel.For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netframework-4.8) from the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace. This is a high-level construct that allows iterations of a loop to run in parallel, without having to control threads in a low-level fashion, as tasks are automatically created for you and scheduled to your processor cores in a way that is optimal for your system.

In the case of your specific code, `Parallel.For` is configured to allow a maximum of `Environment.ProcessorCount * 10` work threads to be scheduled at once. While not a guarantee (the library's schedulers will have the last word), this should ensure that your processing cores are optimally used for the submitted workload, as there are enough tasks to occupy all cores, and a big enough work queue to make sure cores are not starved due to a lack of work scheduled in advance.

**On the C++ side**,

You are using `async` and `future`, which are lower level constructs that allow you to run background tasks, but you are artificially limiting your level of parallelism, by forcing synchronization at each iteration:

```
// Ensure that the background task from the previous iteration
// has completed
f.wait();
```

The easiest (but non-portable) way you can achieve a behavior in C++ that is similar to your C# code, would be to use Microsoft's [Parallel Patterns Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/parallel-patterns-library-ppl?view=vs-2019). This provides a functionality that is very similar to what `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For` provides on the C# side, which is [`concurrency::parallel_for`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/how-to-write-a-parallel-for-loop?view=vs-2019).

Comment: thansk, i'll give it a try

Comment: all right, i tried using parallel_for like you suggest & it did run faster. With my  current code 'parallel_for(0, 10000, [&](int n) {//my function} '. Do you have any tips to improve it even further, in C#, i managed to calculated & used all the threads with Environment.ProcessorCount, can we do the same thing with 'concurrency::parallel_for'?

Comment: There are at least two ways to tune the performance of PPL's parallel_for: by passing a specific partitioner (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/parallel-algorithms?view=vs-2019#partitions) to parallel_for, and by using the concurrency::Scheduler class to tune the algorithm used to schedule jobs.